# npm run dev is no longer running my react app on my local server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, vite

I use Vite to download the react package, `npm run dev` used to open the application on my local server but it has stopped working, i noticed this happens whenever i try to use git and as i pushed some changes (of a different project) to my github repo, the vite app now throws errors when i run the above command on my terminal

please i need to solve this issue as the app is ready for deployment and i cannot afford to start all over

for context here is the error messages i keep getting

```
PS C:\Users\USER\Documents\tail-rx> npm run dev
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\USER\Documents\tail-rx/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\USER\Documents\tail-rx\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-22T20_04_14_503Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\USER\Documents\tail-rx> npm run dev
```

here is the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "tail-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll": "^1.0.12",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.9.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.10.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide your package.json file since the error pointing to that file, probably something wrong with the entry point or your file is missing

Comment: Can you paste the result of `dir` (powershell) or `ls`? Like the others have said, the `package.json` is not in the working directory from which you're running `npm run dev`.

Comment: i have edited the question with package.json included

Answer (score 0):

If you are encountering an error like "ENOENT" (Error, No Entry), especially when running npm run dev, it typically indicates that a file or directory expected by the script is missing.

**Navigate to your project directory:**

cd

**Run the development script:**

npm run dev